# Replace Entity Framework FromSql() with clean EF Core query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm wondering how to replace my EF `FromSql()` extension with clean Entity Framework Core task.

My query looks like this:

```
 activities = await _context.SubActivities
            .FromSql(SubActivityQueryLibrary.GetRouteCombustionForDevices(deviceIds, dateFrom))
            .Select(dict => new { Key = dict.StartTime, Value = Convert.ToDouble(dict.ConsumptionFuel) })
            .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
            .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

and the SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, StartTime) AS [StartTime], 
    SUM(ConsumptionFuel) AS [ConsumptionFuel]
FROM 
    [Flota24].[dbo].[ACTIVITIES]
WHERE 
    DeviceId IN ({string.Join(",", deviceIds)}) 
    AND StartTime >= '{startDate:yyyy-MM-dd}'
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, StartTime)
```

Just would like to convert hard to maintain SQL code to EF Core. I tried to create something with `SUM`, `GROUP` and `CONVERT()` but always had some troubles.

Comment: `StartTime` is date stored as text, right?

Comment: Please show your efforts. Currently it's not clear where you had "some troubles".

Comment: @IvanStoev the database stores this column as `datetime2(7) not null`. I am using `CONVERT()` because I want to remove the time stamp (the reason is GROUP BY).

Comment: Ok, then `Date` property will do the same. The problem with current EF Core is that it doesn't property translate `GroupBy` server side (always evaluates it client side). You might consider waiting for 2.1 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core task should be replaced with code below:

```
 activities = await _context.SubActivities
            .Where(d => deviceIds.Contains(d.DeviceId) && d.StartTime >= dateFrom)
            .GroupBy(o => o.StartTime.Date)
            .Select(dict => new { Key = dict.Key, Value = Convert.ToDouble(dict.Sum(x => x.ConsumptionFuel)) })
            .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
            .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

SQL Query can be removed.